# Javascript syntax <script /> VS <script></script> - the weirdest thing

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

> #### Duplicate
>
> [Why don’t self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

I'm writing an ASP.net page, which have some Javascript code in JS file for client-side authentication.

While using this code **prevented** from my server-side code from working:

```
<script src="../../JavaScript/BaseJS.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer" />
```

**This code** somehow worked:

```
<script src="../../JavaScript/BaseJS.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

Comment: this is part of the standard, script tags cannot be self closed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [HTML4.01 manual section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) defining the `SCRIPT` element, states:

> 18.2.1 The SCRIPT element
>
> ...
>
> Start tag: **required**, End tag: **required**

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in saying you're testing with IE? This is a [known](http://www.phpied.com/ie-script-tag-problem/) [bug](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-153-self-closing-script-tag-issues.html). (I'm sure there are lots of other pages referring to it too.)

EDIT: In fact, there's [another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) about this too.

Answer (score 0):

`<script>` can only self-close in XHTML, not HTML.

Comment: Script tag cannot self-close even in XHTML. It is valid XML but browsers choke on it.

Comment: Get your facts straight. XHTML is XML, therefore a self-closing SCRIPT element is valid XML. It passes XHTML validation therefore it is valid XHTML. Just because some browsers choke on it, doesn't mean I am incorrect.

Comment: Any proper browser that can handle valid XHTML will accept a self-closed SCRIPT element.

Comment: Any browser that implements real XHTML, that is, when sent with the MIME type application/xhtml+xml (e.g., Firefox, Opera, Safari and Chrome) does support self-closing script elements. However, no browser implements *any* self-closing element in HTML, i.e., when sent as text/html, and they shouldn't.

Comment: IE6 (or IE7, or maybe both) don't support XHTML even when the right MIME type is used. I think it always parses it as HTML, where there's no such thing as a self-closing element as you say.